# javascript latest file not download in IE without cache clear

Tags: browser

I have do to some changes in Javascript files. i deployed in my server and reset IIS.
I tried to launch from IE , the latest modified file changes cannot appear. It reads old file.
If I have to clear the cache , it will work. without clear cache how to work with latest files.

Please give a guidance to resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

//try to get the value for time now and to add it to the script file url as version id

```
<html>
<title>
<script src='http://example.com/js/main.js?ver=<%=DateTime.Now.Ticks%>' 
type='text/javascript' ></script>
<title>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check cache control options in your IIS.

For flushing cache you can use some variables in js links.

For example:

```
http://domain.com/js/main.js
```

and

```
http://domain.com/js/main.js?ver=1
```

downloads same file, but second link downloads file like new resource